# Best way to push lots of realtime data to AWS from Java applications

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jms

I am looking to push large amounts of data from my Java Web Application to AWS. Within my Java application I have some flexibility in the approach/technology to use. Generally I am trying to dump large amounts of system data into a AWS store for historical purposes that can eventually be reported on and server for audit/historical purposes.

1) The Java Web app (N nodes) will push system-diagnostic information to AWS in near-real time.
2) System-diagnostic information will be collected by a custom plugin for the system and push to some AWS end-point for aggregation.
3) New information to push to AWS will be available approx every second
4) Multiple java web apps will be collecting and pushing information to a central serve

I am looking for the best way to transport the data from the java apps to AWS; Ideally the solution would integrate well on the AWS side and not be overly complex to implement on the Java Web app side (ex. I do not want to have to run some other app/DS to provide an intermediary store). I do not have strong opinions on the AWS storage technology yet either.

Example ideas: Batch HTTP POST data from java web app to AWS, use JMS solution to send data out, leverage some Logger technology to "write" to a AWS datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the diagnostic information is not too big I would consider SQS. If you have different classes of data, you can push the different types to different queues. You can then consume the messages in the queue(s) either from servers running in EC2 or on your own servers.

SQS will deliver each message at least once, but you have to be ready for a given message to be delivered multiple times. Duplicates do happen occasionally.

If your payloads are large, you will want to drop them in S3. If you have to go this route, you might want to use SQS as well: create a file in S3 and push a message to SQS with the S3 filename so you make sure all the payloads get processed.

I would imagine that you will push the data packets into SQS and then have a separate process that will consume the messages and insert into a database or other store in a format that supports whatever reporting/aggregation requirements you might have. The queue provides scalable flow control so you size the message consumption/processing for your average data rate, even though your data production rate will likely vary greatly during the day.

SQS only holds messages for a maximum of 14 days, so you must have some other process that will consume the messages and do some long-term storage.

Comment: Thanks Rob - SQS looks interesting. Do you recommend pushing the data from SQS into some other datastore to make it easier to "use" (aka report on) in the future?

Comment: @empire29 I added a paragraph to the answer. Let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: S3 can now autonomously write a message into SQS or SNS (which can be used to fan-out into multiple SQS queues) to notify your back-end each time a new object is created in an S3 bucket, which is much tidier than the data source having to write to both S3 and then send a back-end notification to SQS.  Depending on the scale of your data feed, there's also Amazon Kinesis: http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/